# Android datepicker get date

Tags: android

I placed a datepicker on a layout to let the user select their birthday. I have used datepickerdialogs earlier by clicking on a button and bringing the dialog up. But this time the datepicker itself is on the layout and I can select a date. How can I get the date every time the user changes the day, month or the year?

[image]

**Solution:**

```
dpResult = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.dpResult);

dpResult.init(year, month, day, new OnDateChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth) {

           //here I got all the values I need
    }
    });
```

Comment: do you want to show the date and time on a textView in layout as the user change date?

Comment: This question may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051153/android-ondatechangedlistener-how-do-you-set-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to use  [`init(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth, DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener yourListenerHere)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#init%28int,%20int,%20int,%20android.widget.DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener%29). Did you try this ?

Comment: One other thing: this works when I change the date by clicking the + and - buttons. But how do I handle when I manually enter the date?

Comment: @erdomester Regarding the source code of DatePicker and NumberPicker, I'm afraid you have to make your own component if onDateChangeListener does not work :/ Is your listener called when you change the focus ?

Comment: At first I have Jul 14 2012 in the DatePicker. Now I click on 2012 and change it to 1980 manually. I show the actual date in a textview that still says Jul 14 2012. Now I click on the month, and the textviews shows Jul 14 1979. Now I change 14 to 25 manually, the textview is unchanged. Now I click on the year and the textview says Jul 25 1979. So until I remove the cursor from the day/mth/yr box, the datepicker doesn't realize the change

Comment: I found it! In the onclicklistener method of my button I put dpResult.clearChildFocus(getCurrentFocus()); that removes the focus of the actual edittext, so the onDateChanged works :)