# How do I tell if a datepicker has been changed for Android?

Tags: android, button, datepicker, isenabled

I have a "Set Date" button that is setEnabled(false) when it's pressed. How can I make it setEnabled(true) when the datepicker is changed?

Comment: your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051153/android-ondatechangedlistener-how-do-you-set-this

Answer (score 0):

[From developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html)

```
//The callback used to indicate the user changes\d the date:
DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener
```