# change the elements of a date when clicking on the date in a calender

Tags: android, date, calendar

Here's the situation, I'm building an app for an university.In the calendar activity, On every other date there is different time tables. So a student can click on a date and gets the time table for that day, and when click on another date gets the time table for that day. The time tables are different on every date. And also when clicking on a date i want the day on that particular date.
I'm taking the student data through Strings.

Comment: This might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051153/android-ondatechangedlistener-how-do-you-set-this

Comment: Have you used any calendar library for displaying calendar.

Comment: yes datePickerDialog @krutik

Comment: You can use calendar library https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Comment: thanks, will try that.. @Krutik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add listener to datepicker

```html
atePicker.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Log.d("Date", "Year=" + year + " Month=" + (month + 1) + " day=" + dayOfMonth);

                }
            });
```

you will get changed date in onDateChanged method.